# Laravel iterate input fields

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form with multiple input fields that are named using an id. I am appending the id to the field name so that they are unique. For example:

```
<select name="values_1[]" multiple="">                                                                                                 
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<select name="values_2[]" multiple="">                                                                                                 
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

How can I iterate through just these fields in my controller to extract the values selected?

Comment: will you be having multiple select inputes all named values_1 and values_2 or will there just be a single select input with values_1 and values_2 etc.... if single you dont need values_1[] instead you can just name it values_1 without the bracket

Comment: There will be multiple select inputs

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach :

```
foreach(values_1 as value1){
 // do something
}

foreach(values_2 as value2){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem with this approach is that I don’t know what the id number will be as it is generated from a database

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="values[{{ $id }}]" multiple="">                                                                                                 
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

```
foreach($request->get('values') as $value) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this, but when I submit the form it only sends the last selected value rather than all of the selected values

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="select_multip_values_1[]" multiple="">                                                                                                 
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

you can get all keys from request and then filtre keys like 'values_*'  with regex or contains 'value_' :

```
$requestKeys = collect($request->all())->keys();
$keys = array();
foreach($requestKeys as $key){
    if(Str::contains($key, 'select_multip_values_'){
         array_push($keys , $key);
    }
}
foreach($keys as $key){
    foreach($request[$key] as $select_option){
        // do something
    }
}
```